# Filter data in google spreadsheet api request

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, google-sheets-api

I'm using a google spreadsheet to get data from an "api" to my vue.js website.

I'm collecting all data for now and I would like to know if this was possible for me to get data with a condition on a table column like "category == 'football'". And then i get only row with the catefory football like in an SQL request.

Here is my created code and this.items is a simple array :

```
created(){
            this.axios.get("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/my-id/1/public/full?alt=json")
            .then(response => (this.items = response.data.feed.entry))
        },
```

And if this is not possible do someone have any idea on how to filter directly in my array.

Answer (score 1):

@AntoineKurka something like this may work for you.

```
async created() {
  let response = await this.axios.get("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/my-id/1/public/full?alt=json")
  let items = response.data.feed.entry
    
  let filteredItems = items.filter(item => {
    return item.category === 'football'
  })
}
```

Where `filteredItems` will be your filtered array.
If you were planning on then setting this array to a property in your `data()` section, you could instead just do

```
this.someProperty = items.filter(item => {
  return item.category === 'football'
})
```